# Kotlin type inference faild

Tags: android, kotlin

When I use both Kotlin and Java in my project
In Java BaseActivity.class:

```
public abstract <T extends BaseViewModel> Class<T> bindViewModel();
```

And when I extend BaseActivity In Kotlin :

```
override fun <T : BaseViewModel<*, out IBaseView<*>>?> bindViewModel(): Class<T> {
    return ArchViewModel::class.java
}
```

the Kotlin remind me the return is type inference faild

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:
required:Class<T>
found:Class<ArchViewModel>
```

How to fix this issue?

P.S. the ArchViewModel.class extends BaseViewModel

Answer (score -1):

Type inference isn't failing. Your method signature says it can return `Class<T>` for any `T` (which extends `BaseViewModel`) you ask for, so it can be called e.g. as

```
activity.bindViewModel<SomeRandomModel>()
```

and must return a `Class<SomeRandomModel>`. Since `ArchViewModel::class.java` isn't a `Class<SomeRandomModel>`, the implementation is incorrect.

It's actually impossible to implement correctly whether in Kotlin or in Java. If `return ArchViewModel.class` compiles in Java, that's because you use the raw type `BaseViewModel`, so the compiler gives up on typechecking and doesn't report the error.

So you need to fix the method so it *can* be implemented. How, depends on what you actually want from it.

Alternately, you can "fix" it by casting `return ArchViewModel::class.java as Class<T>`. The compiler will correctly warn you that this cast is unsafe.